# How to install PeaZip

Tags: software-installation

Does anyone know how to install PeaZip on elementaryOS?

I get the following error when I try to install the .deb file:

"The package is of bad quality"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully installed it with dpkg and gdebi.

Be sure to use this link https://osdn.jp/dl/peazip/peazip_6.1.0.LINUX.GTK2-2_i386.deb (taken from the download page http://www.peazip.org/peazip-linux.html, DEB link under the GTK 2 category)

**Installation with dpkg**

From a terminal :

```
sudo dpkg -i peazip_6.1.0.LINUX.GTK2-2_i386.deb
```

**Installation with gdebi**

(Be sure to have the package gdebi-gtk `sudo apt-get install gdebi-gtk`)

From Files :

Right-click > Open with > gdebi

Click Install